# Vim change keyboard language.. via shortcut

Tags: vimscript, keyboard-layout

I want to change keyboard language via vimscript shortcut.                                                                                                                                     So that i could type in command mode for instance, 'gis', and then the keyboard would become icelandic. (gis=go is). And when I want the us keyboard i could type in command mode: 'gus'. and then the keyboard would become us.

The following command changes keyboard language to "is" when in the terminal:

```
setxkbmap -layout is
```

So therefore, I have come up with the following in the vimscript file.

```
noremap gis :silent "setxkbmap -layout is"<enter>
noremap gus :silent "setxkbmap -layout us"<enter>
```

But the problem is that it simply doesn't create the desired effect.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You might be interested in `:help langmap` and `:help keymap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
noremap gus :silent !setxkbmap -layout us<enter><C-L>
```

The exclamation mark introduces an external, shell command and <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> redraws the screen.